# SqlCompact ALTER COLUMN WITH IDENTITY

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I'm using SQLServer Compact Edition 4.0.

I Have created a new table dynamically [newtable] with sql that replace a previous one [oldtable].

The table have different name but same structure.
The [oldtable] has a field ID that is a PrimaryKey and Identity.

In order to move all records in the [newtable] easly using this simple SQL

```
"INSERT INTO [newtable] SELECT * FROM [oldtable];"
```

the [newtable] has the field ID that is not and identity.

After moved all records in [newtable] I would like to change the ID field as Identity.

I tried this but doesn't work:

```
"ALTER TABLE [newtable] ALTER COLUMN [ID] int IDENTITY (2,1) NOT NULL"
```

Any Idea?

I need to do this operation with SQL.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You cannot alter a column to be an identity column. You will have to add a new column to have the identity property, and copy the other column to the new column (with `IDENTITY_INSERT` set to ON). Then drop the old column.